# Finding the total of an expression - SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to get a row with the totals for the following formula:

```
=iif(Fields!CreditRatingCode.Value>4,COUNT(CInt(Fields!CurrBalance.Value)),CInt(0))
```

I have tried adding a SUM, but is incorrect.

```
=SUM(iif(Fields!CreditRatingCode.Value>4,COUNT(CInt(Fields!CurrBalance.Value)),CInt(0)))
```

Comment: The problem was that you had a `count` inside the `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

For anyone who might be having a similar question, this is the expression that I came up with:

```
=SUM(iif(Fields!CreditRatingCode.Value>4,CInt(1),CInt(0)))
```